# Why javascript setTimeout is not working and setInterval working for the below program

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying execute a test number slider program, I found that `setTimeout` is not working and `setInterval` is worked for the below program. I don't understand why this is happened.
Please help me.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="slide"></h1>

    </body>
    <script type=text/javascript>

    (function(){
       var i=0,
           numbers = [10,20,30,40,50,60],
           intervalTime = 3000;
        return {
            init:function(){
                console.log(numbers[i] +"-"+ i);
               document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = numbers[i];
              if(i < numbers.length - 1) 
            i++;
           else
                   i=0; 

           setTimeout(this.init,intervalTime); 
               //setInterval(this.init,intervalTime); 


            }

        };      

    }()).init();

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will work only one time. `setInterval` works till the `clearInterval` s called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the `init` method is invoked second time(by the `setInterval` call, `this` inside the handler does not refer to the object that is retuned by the anonymous function. So in the second call `this.init` will be undefined so your callback will no longer gets called.

When you use `setInterval` it need to be called only the first time, then the same callback is called on regular intervals that is why it is working(there is still a bug in calling the `setInterval` multiple times, which is not needed)

You can use `.bind()` to pass a function with a custom context like

```js
(function() {
  var i = 0,
    numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    intervalTime = 500;
  return {
    init: function() {
      console.log(numbers[i] + "-" + i);
      document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = numbers[i];
      if (i < numbers.length - 1)
        i++;
      else
        i = 0;

      setTimeout(this.init.bind(this), intervalTime);
      //setInterval(this.init,intervalTime); 


    }

  };

}()).init();
```

```html
<h1 id="slide"></h1>
```